# Can I cache HTTPS Traffic using Apache as a Forward proxy?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, https

Im trying to speed up a HTTPs website using apache as the proxy & cache. I have my own ssl cert for the proxy, but all show up in the uncached-requests log.

I would prefer to do this with Apache, but if their is something else i can use to proxy & cache the site that would be great.

The relevant part of my apache conf is below showing my current cache attempt.

Thanks

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.fakegoogle.com
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off

    ProxyPass / https://www.google.com/  timeout=30 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / https://www.google.com/

    ProxyAddHeaders Off

    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/sslCert/fakegoogle.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/sslCert/fakegoogle.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/apache2/sslCert/fakegoogle.com.bundle.crt

    <IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
       ProxyRequests on
       CacheRoot proxyCache
       CacheLastModifiedFactor 0.3
       CacheEnable disk /
       CacheIgnoreHeaders None
       CacheRoot "/var/cache/mod_proxy"
       CacheDirLevels 3
       CacheDirLength 5
       CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
       CacheMaxFileSize 100000000
       CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
       CacheMaxExpire 1209600
       CacheDefaultExpire 86400
       CacheStoreNoStore On
       CacheIgnoreQueryString On
       CacheStorePrivate On
    </IfModule>

     <IfModule mod_expires.c>
         ExpiresActive On
         ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 hours"
     </IfModule>

 CustomLog /var/www/logs/cached-requests.log common env=cache-hit
     CustomLog /var/www/logs/uncached-requests.log common env=cache-miss
     CustomLog /var/www/logs/revalidated-requests.log common env=cache-revalidate
     CustomLog /var/www/logs/invalidated-requests.log common env=cache-invalidate

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it is what you are looking for but have you tried to take a look at google mod_spdy? It could help you speed up your website.

https://code.google.com/p/mod-spdy/

Comment: Is this totally out of topic?

Comment: The reason the page it is slow at the moment is because it is being re-written via Apache. So spdy isnt going to solve the issue